# javascript não cria elemento html e não adiciona na pagina

Tags: javascript, funções, dom

Estou começando no `javascript` e queria criar elementos html dinamicamente mas quando carrega a pagina ela fica em branco e não adiciona os elementos
código abaixo:

```
function add (){

    var texto = document.createTextNode("teste");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var ptexto = p.appendChild(texto);
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(ptexto);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Acho que queres inserir o `p` e não o `ptexto` certo?

De qualquer maneira o teu código funciona, vê aqui:

```js
function add() {
  var texto = document.createTextNode("teste");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var ptexto = p.appendChild(texto);
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.appendChild(ptexto);
}

add();
```

Mas acho que o que queres é:

```js
function add() {
  var texto = document.createTextNode("teste");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var ptexto = p.appendChild(texto);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

add();
```

```css
p {
  background-color: #eef;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

E nesse caso não precisas do `textNode`, podes fazer assim:

```js
function add() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = 'teste!!';
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

add();
```

```css
p {
  background-color: #eef;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: obrigado a todos, tentei executar no navegador mas não apareceu, e aparece uma msg a hora que inspeciono a pagina aparece    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined seria algo de configuração?

Comment: Sergio e eu acho que tu queres recordar, vejo que bela song,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rr7TaaJ60Ws

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo :)

Comment: @MarceosDourado isso aparece se estiveres a adicionar o JavaScript dentro do `head`. Coloca no final do `body` ou com `window.load = function(){ /* o código aqui */ }`

Comment: @MarceosDourado Asssim: `[seu html] ... <script src="..."></script></body></html>`