# Criar elementos HTML usando um arquivo externo JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sou novo no JavaScript e gostaria de criar elementos dinamicamente usando arquivo externo JavaScript. Porém estou sem sucesso.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
function add (){

    var texto = document.createTextNode("teste");
    var p = document.createElement("h1");
    var ptexto = p.appendChild(texto);
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(ptexto);

}
```

Não estou conseguindo adicionar os elementos no corpo do documento.

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre esta [e a outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242541/129)?

Comment: O arquivo está adicionado no head e quando executo o código, os elementos não são criados. falaram para adicionar no fina do corpo

Comment: Isso mesmo. No `<head>` vc tá tentando criar um elemento no `<body>` quando o mesmo ainda nem foi lido.

Comment: Estou entendendo que é duplicata sim. Marceos, veja o comentário que deixei na outra pergunta, embaixo da resposta do Sergio.

Comment: obrigado pela informação, sou novo por aqui, estou mais ciente agora